# How to output error messages if split userinput is out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a text based game for a class. This isn't the game; I'm kind of testing the foundation separately. I'm aware of the misspellings and messiness but I'll still take advice on that as I tend to struggle with "style" a lot.

I feel like I'm right on the verge of solving this... There's a dictionary of areas and items and I want the player to have to type "Go" first for a direction or "Get" first if they want to retrieve an Item. This took me so long to figure out and yet once I finally got it I ran into other errors and checks and balances I can't quite seem to wrap my head around.

Right now what works is as follows

- player typing anything other than go/get, an error message occurs
- player typing go/get then a direction or item that doesnt exist, an error message occurs
- If the player tries to receive an Item that DOESN'T exist in a room that DOES contain an Item an error message occurs
- if the player types `exit` the program ends

This is almost perfect.

```py
while action != 'exit':
    status()
    print(inventory)
    action = input('> ').strip().title()
    splitaction = action.split()
    if splitaction[0] == 'Go'.strip().title():
        if splitaction[1] in rooms[current_room]:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][splitaction[1]]
            print(f'You went {splitaction[1]}')
        elif splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room]:
            print('u cant do tht')


    if splitaction[0] == 'Get'.strip().title():
        item = rooms[current_room].get('Item')
        if splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
            print('tht item no exists here')
        elif splitaction[1] in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
            if item not in inventory:
                inventory.append(rooms[current_room].get('Item'))
                print(f'You got the {item}!')
            elif item in inventory:
                print('u alrdy got tht')
    elif action == 'exit'.strip().title():
        print("You've chosen to end the game, goodbye.")
        snooze(2)
        break
```

Right now my current problems

- If the player simply types Go/Get and nothing else I get the following error:

```
if splitaction[1] in rooms[current_room]:
       ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

- If the player tries to retrieve an item in a room that DOESN'T contain one I get the following error:

```
if splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to fix and print error messages for these occassions? I wouldn't be surprised if something very simple is going over my head, my brain got fried from simply making the Go/Get 'kind of' work.

Thing's I've tried:

```
if splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
```

I expected to get error message since there's no item in that room but instead I get `NoneType not iterable`. I properly get the error message only if the room has an item but the one typed doesn't exist.

Also tried

```
if len(splitaction) <= 1
```

then print an error message so it could cover the player simply typing go/get but I still get the out of range error

Tried

```
if splitaction[1] == none
```

for the same effect but nothing is working.

I tried to use a `try`/`except` but I got the same errors. I don't quite know how it works yet. I'm a complete beginner and we didn't go over that in class yet.

Update: Thanks to 0x01010 I was able to fix the out of range issue but I'm still struggling with the `NoneType` error:

```
if splitaction[0] == 'Get'.strip().title():
    item = rooms[current_room].get('Item')
    if getelement(splitaction, 1) not in rooms[current_room]:
        print("That item doesn't exist")
    elif item in rooms[current_room].get("Item"):
        if item not in inventory:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room].get('Item'))
            print(f'You got the {item}!')
        elif item in inventory:
            print('You already have that item!')
```

Right now I get the "Item doesn't exist" even if the item does exist in the current room? If I change the the first nested if statement to `rooms[current_room].get('item')` it brings me back to the nonetype error if the player tries to receive an item in a room that doesn't have one. It works fine if the room does have an item. I'm almost at the final point where the game is at least playable even if not perfect but I don't want the program to crash simply because the player tries to receive an item in a room that doesn't have one.

Comment: I fixed it, and sorry I forgot :)

Comment: rooms[current_room].get("Item") if it is None you can't use "if something in rooms[current_room].get("Item")" becouse in keyword tries to make a loop in value in right but it is None.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function like this

```py
# this function will return null if array doesn't include any element in the index that you gave otherwise function will return the element of index
def getelement(arr: list, i: int):
    if arr is not None and i < len(arr):
        return arr[i]
    return None
```

And change all of

```py
splitation[1]
```

to

```py
getelement(splitation, 1)
```

## Edit

Sorry I forgot to answer the second problem.

Change this line

```py
if splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
```

to

```py
if rooms[current_room].get('Item') is None or splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
```

if "rooms[current_room].get('Item') is None" is True (So it is None) it didn't check second locigal expression because I used "or" between expressions. If one of them is True "or" operator returns
True.

```py
if splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
```

When you creating room if room has no items  'Item' must be empty list, not None.

```py
rooms[current_room].get('Item')
```

mustn't None.
Bu if you can't do it now check is value None:

```py
if rooms[current_room].get('Item') not is None and splitaction[1] not in rooms[current_room].get('Item'):
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work for fixing out of range however i'm still suck on "NoneType" not iterable if you can possibly help with that at all.

Comment: I fixed it, and sorry for that :)